# If someone says , "I had a night out"

Tags: word-usage, time

If someone says

> 'I had **a night out'**.

Whether it means that he stayed up until the next day morning or just that day evening?

Comment: _Night out_ means only _went out at night._ It tells us nothing about duration.

Comment: Depends on the context and the speaker's intention. So, it's ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

> I had a night out.

only means the person was out during the specified night and usually refers to doing *something* sociable and fun. The length or duration of the activity is not implied would need to be specified in surrounding context.

To stay up all night can be specifically referred to as

> an all-nighter
>   We had *an all-nighter* studying for exams and only got to bed this morning.
>
> out all night
>   We were *out all night* and watched the sun rise over the ocean.

Comment: What is the difference between _length_ and _duration,_ @Peter ?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Not to speak for Peter, but, the way I read it, this means: if we say that "Cinderella had a night out," then neither "until midnight" nor "for four hours" would be implied. (I have trouble figuring out which of those is the length, and which is the duration, but somehow I find the answer more understandable with _length or duration_ in the sentence.)

Comment: It was a **long** night (length), I was studying from 8PM until 5AM (duration). It's a subtlety for native speakers, "length" is more general, "duration" is more specific.